# pjax : HTML link that works like a browser back button

Tags: javascript, browser, pjax

I'm using pjax for my website navigation. I need to create a HTML back button that works exactly like the browser back button. But this one should be a simple HTML link. How can I create a pjax link that navigates to the previous page?

I've searched and all the topics seem to be about browser back button, which is not what I want

This is the code that I use for my pjax navigation

```
 $(function() {
        $(document).pjax('.pjax', '#pjax-container', {
            fragment: '#pjax-container',
            timeout: 9000000 ,
        });
    });
```

Comment: `<a href="javascript:history,go(-1)">back</a>` ?

Comment: You can store visited URLs in an array, in a localStorage variable, then navigate to that (`.pop()`).

Answer (score 4):

You can access the browsing history via javascript. See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).

If you just want a simple back link, you can use it like this:

```
<a href="javascript:window.history.back();">go back</a>
```

or like this:

```
<button onclick="window.history.back()">go back</button>
```

Alternatively if you don't want to use `window.history`, your application should maintain browsing history.

You can use events from the pjax library. An example you can follow:

```
// Variable to control history
const myAppHistory = []

// Get current url from event before ajax and put into an variable to control the history
$(document).on('pjax:beforeSend', function(event) {
    const url = event.currentTarget.URL;
    myAppHistory.push(url);
})

// Returns last page visited
function goBack() {
    const url = myAppHistory.pop()
    if (typeof url != "undefined") {
        $.pjax({url: url, container: '#main'})  
    }
}
```

So you use the `goBack()` wherever you need it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a simple HTML link that takes you to the previous page, you can use [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Traveling_through_history) to accomplish that.

You can do it easily by using History API's `window.history.back()` method  and an anchor tag like this:

```
<a href="javascript:window.history.back()">Back</a>
```

or with a button you can do it in `onclick` attribute like this

```
<button onclick="javascript:window.history.back()">Back</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, Just define a function for that...

```
function goBack(){

   window.history.back();

}
```

And then call it like

```
<button onClick="goBack()">Back</button>
```

Or,

```
<a onClick="goBack()">Back</a>
```