# Adding a back button or link to an image file page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been asked to add a back button (or link) to pages on a site that's used to sell photos.
Once the user has selected a picture, they can click on the picture to see a full resolution version in the browser (the jpg file).
These images are big (3000px wide) but need to be viewable full res by prospective purchasers.
This is a Wordpress site using Woocommerce, although it's not, per se, a Wordpress issue.
I've explored various options and although most lightboxes provide a close or back button, these are for images opened in the lightbox and are not full resolution.
Personally, I think this facility is unnecessary, but, the fact that the client wants it would seem to indicate that other users would find it useful.
Here's an example product page:
https://www.guygriffithscollection.com/product/68-783-s-moss-jaguar-silverstone-09-05-1953-jpg/
The site has a simple password entry at the moment: gcdev

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, I think all you need to do is add a button that calls the browser's native back functionality.  See this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54097530/8469201

Comment: Thanks @tyler, I think I'm ok with the code to make the button or link appear. It's just  (and this will make me appear incredibly dumb) where/how do I add the code so that when the image loads the button appears?

Comment: That's where it could get tricky.  You'd have to have an intermediary html page that loads the picture and put the back button on that.  I think the two realistic options you would have are going to be either just opening the full-res file in a new tab (because you're not opening a webpage any more at that point) or find a photogallery solution that allows full-res